# rapidJSON adding an array of structs

Tags: arrays, json, struct

I want to be able to create the following JSON output using rapidJSON

```
{
    "year": 2013,
    "league": "national",
    "teams": [
        {
            "teamname": "reds",
            "teamcity": "cincinnati",
            "roster": [
                {
                    "playername": "john",
                    "position": "catcher"
                },
                {
                    "playername": "joe",
                    "position": "pitcher"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is valid JSON... Verified at JSONLint.com
I know how to create a document and use AddMember to add "year" and "league".

I can not figure out and have not seen any examples of how to add an array that has a structure like "teams" or "roster"

How does one add "teams" which is an array of structures?
Any help or point me to an example would be great.

Comment: Should have accepted the answer

Answer (score 67):

Lets assume we have a std::vector roster containing PlayerName() and Postion() accessor functions on the Roster class that return std::string&.

```
rapidjson::Document jsonDoc;
jsonDoc.SetObject();
rapidjson::Value myArray(rapidjson::kArrayType);
rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType& allocator = jsonDoc.GetAllocator();

std::vector<Roster*>::iterator iter = roster.begin();
std::vector<Roster*>::iterator eiter = roster.end();
for (; iter != eiter; ++iter)
{
    rapidjson::Value objValue;
    objValue.SetObject();
    objValue.AddMember("playername", (*iter)->PlayerName().c_str(), allocator);
    objValue.AddMember("position", (*iter)->Position().c_str(), allocator);

    myArray.PushBack(objValue, allocator);
} 

jsonDoc.AddMember("array", myArray, allocator);
rapidjson::StringBuffer strbuf;
rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(strbuf);
jsonDoc.Accept(writer);

const char *jsonString = strbuf.GetString();  // to examine the encoding...
```

This will get you an array of structures in the document.  All you should need to do to get the rest of the structure is to nest rapidjson objects within each other and use AddMember() to build your complex object tree.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice one! Unfortunately the user didn't accept your answer, anyway you made my day! :)

Comment: Perfect saved a lot my time. the should have accepted your answer

Comment: This is a solid all round example to pull from.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: ප්‍රශ්නේ අහපු user ට හෙන ගහපන්. ඇයි යකෝ මේක accept කළේ නැත්තේ?

Comment: @AmazingSixty any chance you could translate this to English? Google suggests you're trying to get someone to accept this answer, but I'm not sure

Comment: @TankorSmash I was cursing the person who asked the question - why didn't he marked this answer as correct? That was my comment :)

Answer (score 12):

In Vs2012/Rapidjson Version 0.1, following statement gets unreadable code when output document from StringBuffer.

```
objValue.AddMember("position", (*iter)->Position().c_str(), allocator);
```

after a few hours dig, i figured out how to do it in a correctly way.

```
Value tmp;
tmp.SetString( (*iter)->Position().c_str(), allocator);
objValue.AddMember("position", tmp, allocator);
```

here is a tutorial: http://miloyip.github.io/rapidjson/md_doc_tutorial.html

Answer (score 4):

```
rapidjson::StringBuffer s;
    rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(s);

    writer.StartObject();               

    std::string year("year");
    writer.String(year.c_str(), static_cast<rapidjson::SizeType>(year.length()));
    writer.Int(2013);

    std::string league("league");
    writer.String(league.c_str(), static_cast<rapidjson::SizeType>(league.length()));
    std::string national("national");
    writer.String(national.c_str(), static_cast<rapidjson::SizeType>(national.length()));


    std::string teams("teams");
    writer.String(teams.c_str(), static_cast<rapidjson::SizeType>(teams.length()));

    writer.StartArray();
    writer.StartObject();

    std::string teamname("teamname");
    writer.String(teamname.c_str(), static_cast<rapidjson::SizeType>(teamname.length()));
    std::string reds("reds");
    writer.String(reds.c_str(), static_cast<rapidjson::SizeType>(reds.length()));

    std::string teamcity("teamcity");
    writer.String(teamcity.c_str(), static_cast<rapidjson::SizeType>(teamcity.length()));
    std::string cincinnati("cincinnati");
    writer.String(cincinnati.c_str(), static_cast<rapidjson::SizeType>(cincinnati.length()));

    std::string roster("roster");
    writer.String(roster.c_str(), static_cast<rapidjson::SizeType>(roster.length()));

    writer.StartArray();

    writer.StartObject();
    std::string playername("playername");
    writer.String(playername.c_str(), static_cast<rapidjson::SizeType>(playername.length()));
    std::string john("john");
    writer.String(john.c_str(), static_cast<rapidjson::SizeType>(john.length()));

    std::string position("position");
    writer.String(position.c_str(), static_cast<rapidjson::SizeType>(position.length()));
    std::string catcher("catcher");
    writer.String(catcher.c_str(), static_cast<rapidjson::SizeType>(catcher.length()));
    writer.EndObject();

    // can add one more object in the same manner
    // with player name and position

    writer.EndArray();

    writer.EndObject();

    writer.EndArray();
    writer.EndObject();


s.GetString();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Pointers](https://rapidjson.org/md_doc_pointer.html) are the nicest way to build objects with rapidjson. You basically give it a path and set the value at that path. It allows convenient nesting because the path is created if it doesn't exist.

The [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library, which has recently been adopted by the c++ standard library as std::format, is very useful for helping us create the paths.

**Setup**

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY
#include <fmt/format.h>

#include <rapidjson/document.h>
#include <rapidjson/pointer.h>
#include <rapidjson/stringbuffer.h>
#include <rapidjson/writer.h>

using namespace rapidjson;

struct Player {
    std::string playername;
    std::string position;
};

struct Team {
    std::string teamname;
    std::string teamcity;
    std::vector<Player> roster;
};

std::vector<Team> teams = {
    {"reds", "cincinnati", {{"john", "catcher"}, {"joe", "pitcher"}}}
};
```

Rapidjson pointer paths take a number to be an array index (*if the number is not a key at the given path*). We can take advantage of that by using the index of the vector as we iterate old school, while all the array creation is handled for us.

**Main**

```cpp
Document doc;

Pointer("/year").Set(doc, 2013);
Pointer("/league").Set(doc, "national");

for (size_t i = 0; i < teams.size(); ++i) {
    auto team_name = fmt::format("/teams/{}/teamname", i);
    auto team_city = fmt::format("/teams/{}/teamcity", i);

    Pointer(team_name.data()).Set(doc, teams[i].teamname.data());
    Pointer(team_city.data()).Set(doc, teams[i].teamcity.data());

    for (size_t j = 0; j < teams[i].roster.size(); ++j) {
        auto name = fmt::format("/teams/{}/roster/{}/playername", i, j);
        auto position = fmt::format("/teams/{}/roster/{}/position", i, j);

        Pointer(name.data()).Set(doc, teams[i].roster[j].playername.data());
        Pointer(position.data()).Set(doc, teams[i].roster[j].position.data());
    }
}
```

**Finally, get JSON string from Document**

```cpp
StringBuffer buffer;
Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
doc.Accept(writer);

auto json_str = buffer.GetString();
```